# Xterra goes limp, dashboard goes dark at random

Tags: electrical, nissan, intermittent-problems, xterra

I have a 2002 Nissan Xterra with 96K miles on it.

Once in a while, the instrument panel goes dark. No speedometer, fuel gauge, etc. I can't drive over 30 mph either. The next time I start the car everything is fine again.

Three garages check it our for me, including a dealer. No one found the root cause.

Has anyone had a similar experience and knows how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: What did those garages check?

Comment: so the instrument panel cuts out completely? no gauges indicator lights etc? is the check engine light on? any stored codes in any of the modules?

Comment: Did you ever tryout our theory?

Answer (score 1):

It's the ECU. Somehow water or moisture invaded that region. You get the dashboard removed behind the cooling coil you'll locate the ECU metallic box, swap it out inspect it for any mineral buildup. If you find any head over to eBay/Amazon/craigslist/junk yard to find an ECU with less mileage and warranty.